# Installing readahead on Debin 9

Tags: boot, debian, package-management

Recently installed debian 9 on my computer. I'd like to install the package 'readahead' but seems like I cannot find it. Should I install it from a previous debian version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `readahead` is only available for debian Wheezy and Jessie. Also it has removed from systemd.

> systemd's readahead implementation has been removed. In many
>     circumstances it didn't give expected benefits even for
>     rotational disk drives and was becoming less relevant in the
>     age of SSDs. As none of the developers has been using
>     rotating media anymore, and nobody stepped up to actively
>     maintain this component of systemd it has now been removed.

[Freedesktop-systemd-line#n950](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/NEWS#n950)

> In Linux distributions that use systemd, readahead binary (as part of the boot sequence) was replaced by systemd-readahead.[4][5] However, support for readahead was removed from systemd in its version 217, being described as unmaintained and unable to provide expected performance benefits

[readahead on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readahead)

> Should I install it from a previous debian version?

Installing a package from a previous debian distribution is possible using the pinning way, but it is not recommended.